# Answer should be auto-bountied if it was the only one to ever exist and the reason was for rewarding an existing answer

Tags: feature-request, bounties, accepted-answer

I posted a bounty on [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/186923/102999) on May 27, intending to reward it to the person who had a highly upvoted answer that was accepted on May 19. The reason I chose from those available was

> One or more of the answers is exemplary and worthy of an additional bounty.

When the time was up, I forgot to actually give the user the bounty. The system didn't automatically give it, even though **it was the only answer there when I started the bounty and there are no deleted answers that were ever posted to the question.**

**I propose that, if the exemplary answer reward bounty reason is chosen and there was only one answer when the bounty was added and none were posted during it, the bounty should automatically be given in full to the pre-existing answer.**

Comment: How is this unclear?

Comment: I mean the wording is kind of weird I guess

Comment: First thing I ask myself is - what if the answer gets edited in a way that it's no longer exemplary? Well, we should check that and prevent it if the answer is edited. But then I think - shit, but what if it got edited into something _even better_? How can that be determined automatically? It can't... We probably shouldn't automate too much stuff

Comment: Don't you get a reminder once the bounty is in the grace period?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek No, not always. IIRC some sites have disabled it.

Comment: Strange how many more votes the thing this was a dupe of got.

Answer (score 5):

### How can the system be sure it's worthy of it?

Automation is nice, but automation requires failsafes. Do we want to auto-reward some not stellar answer that just one guy (the bountier) deemed exceptional? No, we don't really want to.

There's an auto-reward​ on new answers to bountied questions, provided the new answers are posted after the bounty started, got a +3 score, etc, etc. That's okay because there's community reviewing of said answer (+3 score condition), so we know the auto-reward will be deserved.

In the case you describe, there's no such a check, so the system might give "points" to meh answers, ... Which, again, is not really what bounties are for.

---

A slight suggestion which I think would improve the feature request: have half the bounty be awarded if that single "exemplary" answer got a +X score increase during the bounty's duration. That'd be a similar "awarded 'cause peer review says it's good" check than the current "minimum +3 score" condition.

Comment: Well why not give the bounty to the answer the bountier clearly wanted to give it to in case they forgot to reward it like I did?

Comment: @Stormblessed to ensure that next time, the bountier won't forget? ;)

Comment: @Stormblessed - You were sent multiple notifications, the bounty was to expire, and there isn’t a 24 hour grace period.

Comment: @Stormblessed Why didn't you award the bounty immediately after applying it, if you knew exactly which answer you wanted to give it to as soon as you applied the bounty?  Why risk forgetting?